# using split() to split values in an entire column in a python dataframe

Tags: string, csv, pandas, split

I am trying to clean a list of url's that has garbage as shown.

1. /gradoffice/index.aspx(
2. /gradoffice/index.aspx-
3. /gradoffice/index.aspxjavascript$
4. /gradoffice/index.aspx~

I have a csv file with over 190k records of different url's. I tried to load the csv into a pandas dataframe and took the entire column of url's into a list by using the statement

```
str = df['csuristem']
```

it clearly gave me all the values in the column. when i use the following code - It is only printing 40k records and it starts some where in the middle. I don't know where am going wrong. the program runs perfectly but is showing me only partial number of results. any help would be much appreciated.

```
import pandas
table = pandas.read_csv("SS3.csv", dtype=object)
df = pandas.DataFrame(table)
str = df['csuristem']
for s in str:
    s = s.split(".")[0]
    print s
```

I am looking to get an output like this

1. /gradoffice/index.
2. /gradoffice/index.
3. /gradoffice/index.
4. /gradoffice/index.

Thank you,
Santhosh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do the following, so call `.str.split` on the column and then `.str[0]` to access the first portion of the split string of interest:

```
In [6]:

df['csuristem'].str.split('.').str[0]
Out[6]:
0    /gradoffice/index
1    /gradoffice/index
2    /gradoffice/index
3    /gradoffice/index
Name: csuristem, dtype: object
```